# Can I ask about school boards here

Tags: discussion, support

I am on a school board for a small private elementary school, and we're having some trouble between one of our teachers and the administrator which I won't go into on meta, but would like to ask about.  Would academia be an appropriate forum (doesn't seem right, but I don't know where else to ask) to ask about interactions between faculty and staff?

Answer (score 3):

I was going to say initially that this question was off-topic, but I'm actually not so sure. It really does depend on the issue.

The rule that we have is that questions that aren't set at the postgraduate level are off-topic unless they'd also be relevant here. So it really does become a question of what the specific problem is. If it's something that could also take place between a professor and staff at a university, then it could be on-topic.

Alternately, you can take a look and see if this might be appropriate over at [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you frame it generally enough, it would be on topic, as it's a general question. However, do note that this forum is intended for university-level discussion, so the responses may not actually be relevant to your situation. That said, I would post it and see what answers you get. Good luck!